# My code Codecademy is not working in my pc my (Jquery Ui code or jsscript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am study in Codecademy all ready. But while i am learning in the codecademy I copy the code because I forget quickly.
This code I put in my program for make website. The problem is when I want to view the page in my PC(i dont have host). the code is not working.

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).effect('bounce',{times:3} , 500);
    });
});
```

The markup:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
    </body>
```

you can observe the code HTML have a two link in the  that link are connecting  the script

someone tell me i have to download the Jquery if i want to make the web in my computer is the link  http://qunitjs.com/ but i dont know which file download.

what can i do ?

Comment: You should be able to open the html file in your browser

Comment: Take a look at [this W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) tutorial on installing jQuery. I'm not sure exactly what problem you are having, so I assume you must have had an issue with using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory name it: example01
In this directory create three files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).effect('bounce',{times:3} , 500);
    });
});
```

open index.html in browser and watch the result

Comment: YEAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHhh u are the puto moster : D : ) : D

Comment: in my host make too this ?

Answer (score 0):

i did and nothing

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <body>
    <div ></div>
    </body>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in the head tags

```
<head>
<script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```